# truffle console: Can't execute function i.e., TypeError: SimpleContract.at(...).getName is not a function

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-console

I am trying to familiarize with 'truffle console' by doing the tutorial at:

https://medium.com/oli-systems/test-driven-solidity-with-truffle-e4beaa2bd194

$truffle migrate

> ## Compiling your contracts...
>
> > Compiling ./contracts/SimpleContract.sol : : 2_deploy_contracts.js
> > =====================
>
> Deploying 'SimpleContract'    --------------------------
>
> > transaction hash:    0xd92a66361f9145398ec0ce5e2a90e2a97f5c10015475b3d2cabcba75eec14e5c
> > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
> > ***contract address:    0xDa0463c841E7D822f6281240cD7593bA3FD4BB0f***
> > block number:        5
> > block timestamp:     1610603088
> > account:             0x47FBfdC7eC99871c2D9fFDdd3D77e6c70F727556

```
truffle(development)> SimpleContract.at ('0xDa0463c841E7D822f6281240cD7593bA3FD4BB0f');
```

> TruffleContract {   constructor:    { [Function: TruffleContract]
> _constructorMethods:
> { configureNetwork: [Function: configureNetwork],    /*more*/
>
> source:
> '//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT\npragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.7.0;\n \ncontract SimpleContract {\n  string  public name;\n  constructor() public {\n     name = 'my name';  \n  }\n  **function
> getName() public view returns(string memory) {\n      return (name);\n
> }**\n   function changeName(string memory
> _name) public {\n      name = _name;\n   }\n}\n', :
>
> /*more */

```
 truffle(development)> SimpleContract.at('0xDa0463c841E7D822f6281240cD7593bA3FD4BB0f').getName();
```

> Thrown: evalmachine.:0
> SimpleContract.at('0xDa0463c841E7D822f6281240cD7593bA3FD4BB0f').getName();
> ^
>
> TypeError: SimpleContract.at(...).getName is not a function
> at evalmachine.:0:65
> at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:288:15)
> at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:14)
> at runScript (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:494964:21)
> at Console.interpret (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:494979:21)
> at ReplManager.interpret (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:304740:18)
> at bound (domain.js:402:14)
> at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:415:12)
> at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:642:10)
> at REPLServer.emit (events.js:198:13) truffle(development)>

Somebody please guide me how to invoke functions using 'truffle console'?

Zulfi.

Comment: Since it is an old tutorial if you add enough `await` it should work: 1/ `> sc = SimpleContract.at('0x12341234...')`. 2/ `> await sc.getName()`.

Comment: @Ismael, Getting Error: > sc = SimpleContract.at('0xDa0463c841E7D822f6281240cD7593bA3FD4BB0f');"Testing"
'Testing'
truffle(development)> await sc.getName();
Thrown:
TypeError: sc.getName is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:12

Comment: Try `sc = await SimpleContract.at('0x...')`, also adding `await ` to the first command.

Comment: Your solution worked.

Comment: How did you write it?
sc = await SimpleContract.at(‘0x12341234…’); await sc.getName();
Something like that? I didn't catch that.

Comment: @usarotonkachi You have to write in the Truffle console each command `sc = await SimpleContract.at(‘0x12341234…’);`, replacing `SimpleContract` with the contract you want to interact with, and `‘0x12341234…’` with the contract address where it was deployed.